# Linked css does not load even with correct file structure

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Apheleon Hair Salon</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
        <script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy/0.1.3/scrollspy.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollify/1.0.19/jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css"/>
        <script>
        $(function() {
          $.scrollify({
            section : ".page",
            scrollbars:false,
            overflowScroll:true,
            scrollspeed:200,
          });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
```

I have linked my to my css within my html (just above my script) yet the css isn't working and I haven't a clue why. My css file is called "css.css" and it is within a file called "css". I attempted to minify the css, which seemingly broke it (I am sure it wasn't broken before) then rolled that back yet it still does not work.

Comment: have you cleared the browser cache after your rollback?

Comment: When you navigate to the expected URL with your browser (e.g. `https://example.com/css/css.css`), do you get the expected result or do you get an error page?

Comment: I get the css file. The css also won't load when I load the file in my browser offline

Comment: what do you mean whit _The css also won't load when I load the file in my browser offline_

Comment: If I just load up the "index.html" in google chrome, not the website version

Comment: If the CSS file is in the folder called "css" the the href of the link should be "/css/css.css" no?

Comment: Before loading the page, open the Developer Tools of your browser (hit F12) and navigate to the "Network" tab. Load the page and check if you 1.) see the request for "css/css.css" and b.) which server status and content you receive (it should be status code 200). If you want to force the browser to reload a file after a change it's also good to add a hash of some sort to the URL of the changed file e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css?2"/>`.

Comment: The status for the css for me is "Finished", I imagine this is something to do with my error then?